# reading ncurses stdin in UTF-8

Tags: c, utf-8, ncurses

In my Linux program being developed in C with ncurses I need to read the stdin in UTF-8 encoding. However, whenever I do :

```
wint_t unicode_char=0;
get_wch(&unicode_char);
```

I get the wide character in utf-16 encoding (I can see it when I dump the variable with gdb). I do not want to convert it from utf-16 to utf-8, I want to force the input to be in UTF-8 all the time, no matter which Linux distribution runs my program with whatever foreign language the user has it configured. How is this done? Is it possible?

***EDIT***:
Here is the example source and proof that internally get_wch uses UTF-16 (which is the same as UTF-32) and not UTF-8, despite that I configured UTF-8 input source with setlocale().

```
[niko@dev1 ncurses]$ gcc -g -o getch -std=c99 $(ncursesw5-config --cflags --libs) getch.c 
[niko@dev1 ncurses]$ cat getch.c 
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ct;
wint_t unichar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); /* make sure UTF8 */
    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    ct = get_wch(&unichar); /* read character */
    mvprintw(24, 0, "Key pressed is = %4x ", unichar);

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Testing code with GDB:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at getch.c:18
18      mvprintw(24, 0, "Key pressed is = %4x ", unichar);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install ncurses-libs-5.9-21.20150214.fc23.x86_64
(gdb) print unichar
$1 = 128270
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned short*) (&unichar))[0]
$2 = 0xf50e
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned short*) (&unichar))[1]
$3 = 0x1
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned char*) (&unichar))[0]
$4 = 0xe
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned char*) (&unichar))[1]
$5 = 0xf5
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned char*) (&unichar))[2]
$6 = 0x1
(gdb) print/x ((unsigned char*) (&unichar))[3]
$7 = 0x0
(gdb)
```

The input character is , and its UTF-8 should be 'f09f948e' as stated here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50e/index.htm

How do I get UTF8 directly from get_wch() ?? Or maybe there is another function ?

P.S.
if you test the source code, link against *'-lncursesw'* , not *'-lncurses'* or compile with the same command as I did above

Comment: Just guessing: Perhaps setting the locale might help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

Comment: If you want UTF-8, why are you reading wide characters? BTW UTF-16 on Linux is not something that is routinely supported by random software. You are probably getting UCS4.

Comment: "I want to force the input to be in UTF-8 all the time". You want a function `force_everything_to_utf8()` but it doesn't exist (yet). You need to determine the input encoding somehow (this is generally impossible) and translate it to UTF-8 yourself.

Comment: @DanielJour I already have setlocale(LC_ALL,"") at the beginning of the program but it doesnt help much. And , if I force , for example, setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.UTF-8") I will have problems with the input in all foreign languages that is not english. Or is it possible to setlocale to something like: setlocale(LC_ALL,"*.UTF-8") ? If not, maybe this could suggest this to software maintainers?

Comment: @n.m. I am reading wide characters with get_wch() because if I use only getch(), despite that it returns an int of 32 bits, it only provides the first byte of the unicode encoded character, so for multibyte strings I only get the first byte.

Comment: @Nulik Yes, UTF-8 can be encoded in multiple bytes. But getch() will only read 1 byte. Your current approach is the most likely to work everywhere. get_wch() will convert input from whatever encoding is used, and mvprintw() will convert the output back to the encoding the user uses (most likely it will be UTF-8 in both cases).  Treating a single integer as a multibyte encoded UTF-8 character is something you should not need to do  - do you have a particular problem that you solve by doing so ?

Comment: To unpack @nos comment, if you need UTF-8 then you have to read it as UCS-32 first using `get_wch` then convert it to UTF-8 as a separate step. Alternatively try `get_wstr`, but you may find the semantics slightly different than what you are looking for.

Comment: `getch` returns a single byte converted to an `int`, but  a character can occupy several bytes. accordingly, you need to call `getch()` several times to read a single Unicode character.

Comment: @nos I just want to treat all my strings inside my program in UTF-8, that's it. So, if we can set user's input to UTF-8 we will avoid the conversion step.

Comment: Setting the user's input is not up to you. When dealing with internationalized terminal IO, always imagine a hardware terminal attached to a serial line (ncurses is set to handle that). What happens if it's a Chinese terminal set up to output BIG5 encoding? There is no setting you can flip to cause it output UTF-8. This is also the case with lots of software terminals.

Comment: Having said that, your program should work well in practice with UTF8 terminals if you just use getch() and call it as many times as needed to get each character. If you want to read strings delimited by some special characters, then something like `while((ch = getch()) != myspecialcharacter) { add_to_string(str, ch); }` is all you need, exactly like you would do with ASCII (that's the power and beauty of UTF-8, you usually don't need to change your algorithms).

Comment: @n.m. you have got the part of the answer to my question, I tested getch() multiple times and I get the correct input which is 'f09f948e'. I have to do getch() 4 times since is its 4 byte sequence. But the problem now is, how do I know the delimiter for the end of the character sequence if the user copy/pastes many multi-byte characters?

Comment: The first byte of the UTF-8 sequence determines how many bytes are in there, see e.g. `man utf-8` or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). But preferably you should just pretend you are working with ASCII strings of unknown length. How do you know the user have finished with a string? Because he pressed Enter, not because you have counted characters somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: you **don't** get `UTF-8` from [`get_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html).  That returns a `wint_t` (and a status code).

Long: you **would** get `UTF-8` from ncurses [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) because it converts to/from `wchar_t` internally:

- Your program would have to read the encoded character one byte at a time, because `getch` only returns bytes (possibly combined with video attributes).
- ncurses stores `wchar_t` values in the cells of each window structure.
- `addch` and friends attempt to collect bytes for multibyte encodings (it's **not** specific to `UTF-8`, but not much used aside from this).
- The attempt fails if you move the cursor in the middle of a string.

For what it's worth, [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) reads UTF-8 using `getch`.  See [`inputstr.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/inputstr.c) to see how it works in practice.

X/Open curses as such does not do this (for the rare individual actually using Unix curses with UTF-8, there's no specified way).