# Read UTF-8 encoded character from keyboard in ncurses

Tags: c++, utf-8, ncurses

When reading keyboard input in nCurses I use getch() function which works fine for ASCII characters but fails for UTF-8 encoded characters. If I push character ś on the keyboard:

```
int c = getch();
```

Value of c should be in hex: 0xC59B. But when I try to print its value I get only 0xC5.

How I can read a whole character and is getch() correct function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getch`'s name comes from the Old Earth meaning of "character" which is actually just "byte". Multibyte encodings are not understood by this mechanism.

However, [it is still the right function to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110448/560648); you just need to deal with its result properly. Call it repeatedly and dump what you get into a string of bytes (in your particular example, you'll need two calls to obtain enough bytes to represent the particular Unicode character provided), then [interpret those bytes with a UTF-8 library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19182438/560648).

Don't forget to filter out "special values" that `getch` can provide, as [it does not always give you raw characters](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) (consider, for example the <kbd>F1</kbd> key!).

Comment: You are right, I should read all bytes. When I called it second time I got 0x9B.

Answer (score 3):

`getch` reads bytes, but UTF-8 is multibyte.  You could read that byte-by-byte and interpret it, but that's work that most do not need..  Use [`get_wch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html) to read a (whole) *wide character*.

That assumes you've [initialized](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) ncurses' locale:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

(if you don't do that, `getch` would not return the correct bytes, anyway).

Comment: Just reading wide characters does not give you UTF-8, and it does not mean you will get a full Unicode character per call. That's why I recommend `getch()` plus decoding on top, as does the answer I reference, which you wrote!! (This is also why the Windows API convention of wide-chars everywhere is theoretically broken, though it's sort of mitigated by the fact that UTF-16 is somewhat mandated in that environment)

Comment: OP asked to read a **whole character** which was UTF-8 encoded.  `get_wch` does exactly what was asked.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110448/560648) is wrong then?

Comment: That asked for a different point: the ***result*** had to be in UTF-8.  In this question, the ***result*** had to be a whole (wide) character.  There's a difference.

Comment: OP wants to "read UTF-8 characters". That's all that was stated. No mention of wide characters at all. (They have printed the result of `getch` to console to examine what was produced by this call, and expressed the result they expected if the call were to provide all codepoints that make up the character.)

Comment: Read the question: ***How I can read a whole character*** (hth).  Also "Value of c should be in hex: 0xC59B." shows that OP understood what a whole character might look like (though the expected value is incorrect: I see 0x15b).

Comment: "Whole character", not "wide character", and I don't think the "hth" snark was called for... so let's agree to disagree.